# Error appears in sql when trying to add multiple foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to create an index and multiple foreign keys in mysql but when I Include the code below:

```
CREATE INDEX par_ind on Image_Question (SessionId,QuestionId);

ALTER TABLE Image_Question ADD CONSTRAINT FK_CONSTRAINT_NAME
                           FOREIGN KEY (SessionId,QuestionId) 
                             REFERENCES Question(SessionId,QuestionId)
                             ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

The create index worked fine but it doesn't allow me to alter the table and add the foreign keys. It i giving me an error stating:

```
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mobile_app`.<result 2 when explaining filename '#sql-4517_14f1a'>, CONSTRAINT `FK_CONSTRAINT_NAME` FOREIGN KEY (`SessionId`, `QuestionId`) REFERENCES `Question` (`SessionId`, `QuestionId`) ON)
```

What does this error mean and how can I sort this error out?

Below is the Image_Question Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Image_Question (ImageQuestionId INT     NOT NULL, 
                             ImageId          INT     NOT NULL,
                             SessionId        CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
                             QuestionId       INT     NOT NULL,
                            PRIMARY KEY (ImageQuestionId)
                            ) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Below is the Question Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Question (QuestionId INT      NOT NULL, 
                       SessionId  CHAR(3)  NOT NULL,
                       Question   CHAR(10) NOT NULL ) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here i have sorted out your problem and worked fine for me

```
ALTER TABLE `question`     CHANGE `QuestionId` `QuestionId` INT(11) NOT NULL,    ADD PRIMARY KEY(`QuestionId`);
```

first i have changed  the `QuestionId` to `primary key`

```
ALTER TABLE `image_question` ADD INDEX `questionId` (`QuestionId`);
```

then added the index on `QuestionId` of `image_question`

```
ALTER TABLE  `question` ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_question` FOREIGN KEY (`QuestionId`)
REFERENCES `image_question` (`QuestionId`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ;
```

and then first relationship for `QuestionId` works successfully

```
ALTER TABLE `question`     CHANGE `SessionId` `SessionId` INT(11) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE `image_question`     CHANGE `SessionId` `SessionId` INT(11) NOT NULL;
```

then changed the data type of `SessionId` of both tables to `int`

```
ALTER TABLE `image_question` ADD INDEX `NewIndex1` (`SessionId`);
```

then added index on `SessionId` of `image_question`

```
ALTER TABLE `image_question` ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_image_question` FOREIGN KEY (`SessionId`) REFERENCES `question` (`SessionId`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ;
```

and here is your second relationship for `SessionId` hope it works fine for you also