# mysql error #1452 appearing when trying to add a constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, database

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error appears in sql when trying to add multiple foreign keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12657166/error-appears-in-sql-when-trying-to-add-multiple-foreign-keys)

I am trying to alter a table so That I can add a foreign key constraint in mysql database:

```
ALTER TABLE  `Question` ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_question` FOREIGN KEY (`QuestionId`)
REFERENCES `Image_Question` (`QuestionId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ;
```

Problem is that it is giving me this error:

> 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mobile_app`.
>
> '#sql-4517_15241'>, CONSTRAINT `FK_question` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`QuestionId`) REFERENCES `Image_Question` (`QuestionId`) ON DELETE
>   CASCADE)

What does this error actually mean and what are the possible solutions I might have to undertake in order to fix this?

Comment: Why do you ask the same question twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably `Image_Question.QuestionId` is not unique. And it also looks like the FK should go the other way around, from `Image_Question` to `Question`

Comment: +1, it's seems fairly likely that the foreign key should be the other way around.