# MySQL Creating a table with foreign keys from another table : errno:150 occurs.

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create 2 tables in MySQL where the second table has a foreign key from my base table.

The problem is when I try to create the second table I get errno:150. Which fails because the foreign keys are null.

How can I create the second table properly?

**More details**

My first table has 5 attributes and the first attribute is the Primary key.

My second table has 3 attributes. The 1st and 2nd attribute of this table reference the first 2 attributes from the first table.

All the variables are `varchar` and all are same length. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the exact error that you are getting? What happens if you create table 2 and then manually add the foreign key constraints?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12657166/error-appears-in-sql-when-trying-to-add-multiple-foreign-keys/12658951#12658951 this might help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the proper way to fix this, given that we can't see your code, would be on [MySQL - Foreign Key documentation page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html).

See their example below:

```
CREATE TABLE parent (id INT NOT NULL,
                     PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
CREATE TABLE child (id INT, parent_id INT,
                    INDEX par_ind (parent_id),
                    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES parent(id)
                      ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

This line is precisely what you need to do : `FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES parent(id)`.

Comment: I ended up just adding the constraints later in the program. It saved me the trouble.